# 401 error when try to connect to Lighthouse API

Tags: c#, api, lighthouse

I'm trying to connect to the Lighthouse api using C# code. This is the php example https://support.lighthouserocks.com/hc/en-gb/articles/201319732-API-The-Basics which it describe how to do this. But I'm fails with it. I was try both NetworkCredentials & send in the Header but still have 401 Unauthorized access to it, here is the code:

```
public string RequestResponse()
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(HomeUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
    webRequest.Method = "GET";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
    webRequest.Timeout = 20000;

    string auth = CreateAuthorization("domain.lhlive.com", "user", "token");
    webRequest.Headers["auth"] = "Basic " + auth;

    //webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "token");
    //webRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
    //webRequest.Headers.Add("auth", "user, token");
    webRequest.Accept = "application/vnd.lighthouse.v1.hal+json";

    Stream responseStream = null;
    StreamReader responseReader = null;
    string responseData = "";
    try
    {
        WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
        responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (responseStream != null)
        {
            responseStream.Close();
            responseReader.Close();
        }
    }

    return responseData;
}

public void Test()
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (Compatible; Windows NT 5.1; MSIE 6.0) (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
        client.Headers["ContentType"] = "application/json";
        client.Headers["Accept"] = "application/vnd.lighthouse.v1.hal+json";
        //client.Headers["Lighthouse Username"] = "user";
        //client.Headers["API Key"] = "token";
        client.Headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = "user, token";

        byte[] arr = client.DownloadData("https://domain.lhlive.com/contacts");

        Console.WriteLine("--- WebClient result ---");
        Console.WriteLine(arr.Length);
    }
}
```

anybody know what I should to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say because I can't access Lighthouse but try the following (notice how auth header is set).

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://some.endpoint.com/") as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.Accept = "application/vnd.lighthouse.v1.hal+json";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
webRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = string.Format("Basic {0}",
    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(
        string.Format("{0}:{1}", "your username", "your API key"))));

var response = webRequest.GetResponse();
var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
var data = (new StreamReader(stream)).ReadToEnd();
```

In this case your `Authorization` header looks like `"Basic eW91ciB1c2VybmFtZTp5b3VyIEFQSSBrZXk="`.

Comment: on the line var response = webRequest.GetResponse(); I have the following error Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed. with your code

Comment: Well, the  the verb is not allowed by the resource. Change url or method? At least it's not unauthorized anymore.

Comment: I'm change to another method https://domain.lhlive.com/contacts/1 & it's again return 401 error...

Comment: just forget to add accept method in your example, after this it's work correct